# Taking address of temporary - workaround needed

Tags: c++, gcc, pass-by-reference

I am facing a GCC warning that I want to fix. Basically I am passing to a method a pointer to a local variable, which in my case is perfectly OK. I understand why the compiler tells me that this is a potential problem, but in my case this is OK.

How can I workaround it, on a local space? Passing `-fpermissive` when compiling will make me fail to find future problems. I want to fix this specific problem, or workaround it.

Code is available here:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Integer{
public:
    Integer(int i ){ v = i; };
    int value(){ return v; };
private:
    int v;
};

int foo(Integer *i);

int main()
{
    foo( &Integer(12) );
}

int foo(Integer *i)
{
    std::printf("Integer = %d\n", i->value());
}
```

And compilation gives me:

```
$ g++ test-reference.cpp -O test-reference
test-reference.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test-reference.cpp:15:18: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu3) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

EDIT:

Using `const` (as in making `foo` take a const pointer, and marking `value()` as const) gives the same error.

Comment: @jalf see Mat response, to understand. In my case, the variable is on scope when the function is called.

Comment: Can't you change the function's signature to `int foo(const Integer& i);`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Integer i(12);
foo(&i);
```

That gets rid of the "taking the address of a temporary" problem, which is what you have. You're not passing the address of a local variable (which the above does, and is indeed ok in this case), you're grabbing the address of a temporary.

Obviously, if `foo` tries to hold on to that pointer one way or another, you'll have issues down the line.

Comment: *you're grabbing the address of a temporary which is very suspicious.* No, it is not suspicious.The behavior is well defined,`12.2/3` *Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created*.

Comment: It's no more dangerous than taking a reference to an rvalue.

Comment: Ok, didn't mean to mean it was invalid, just (IMO) suspicious.

Comment: @Mat, I need this to be a one liner "without" temporary variables , as this is a temporary variable generated by a DEBUG macro (in my app, its a struct that maintains information about line, file, time, threadID etc).

Comment: @elcuco:  `{ Integer i(12); foo(&i); }`

Comment: @elcuco: my answer already contains that. The `{}` add nothing of real value.

Comment: @Mat The value is that it makes it clear that at a high-level, this is meant as one operation and is only broken down into two for technical reasons, and it limits the scope of the single-letter `i` var, which could be considered a coding standard taboo if not used in a tightly-confined scope.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename T> const T* rvalue_address(const T& in) {
    return &in;
}
```

In my opinion, it should be just as legal to take a `const T*` as a `const T&`, but this trivial function will handily perform the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

GCC is wrong in this case. Your integer is an rvalue and taking the address of an rvalue is illegal.

> §5.3.1 Unary operators, Section 3
>
> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The
>   operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id.

Clang gives an error in this case:

```
error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'Integer' [-Waddress-of-temporary]
    foo( &Integer(12) );
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: GCC is not wrong, it rejected it with `error:` because it is illegal. `-fpermissive` is a GCC extension that basically says "yeah, all right, I know what you *meant*". Extensions are allowed to do whatever non-standard things they like because, well, they're non-standard extensions.

Comment: The standard requires a diagnostic for any ill-formed program unless otherwise specified. A warning is a diagnostic. Even if GCC emitted just a warning *without* -fpermissive, this would not be a conformance issue.